# HTML5 CSS 3 Flexbox

Tags: css, html

I am trying to make a webpage in HTML5 and CSS3 with PHP and Javascript.I would like to display images-using flexbox- in 3 rows .Each row should contain 4 columns.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="row">
<?php echo "<img   src='assets/img/termekek/$image.png' class='column'   
 >";?>
```

and the css

```
 .row{
      display:flex;
     }
   .column{
     flex:33.33%;
     padding:5px
     }
```

But this does not achieve the desired result.

Can someone help me?

Comment: In what way does it fail?

Comment: The browser displays images stretched  under each other.

Comment: And I am using a pseudo class inside a php tag.I am not sure if that is correct.

Comment: you are looking for flex-basis  not flex

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just missing a container to contain the row and columns. The container will need to have `display:flex` and a `flex-direction`.

Here is an example:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And the CSS would be:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1,
    flex-direction: row;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: inherit;
    width: inherit;
}

.column {
    flex: 1;
    border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

*Please ignore the border, height and width properties. They were used to allow a better visualization of the elements on the web page*

The above would result in a container with three rows. Now, if you add three `<div class="column">` in the `<div class="row">`, each row will contain four columns.

There is another way to get the same pattern which involves interchanging the flex-direction between the `.row` and `.container`. However, it would become a *column of rows* instead of a *row of columns*. Just a small detail to think about while you create your elements.

By the way, I got accustomed with using flex by following this guide: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/. Take a look and play around with it!

Happy coding! :)